# Swipe from UITableView to UIButton via UIFocusGuide not working

Tags: tvos

I’m having trouble swiping right to move focus from a UITableView to a UIButton that is to the right and below the tableview. I’ve set up a UIFocusGuide and I believe I’ve got the geometry correct. (See attached screenshot, created using Pod VisualFocusGuide.)

When I use the built-in QuickLook on the UIFocusUpdateContext, it shows only the table view focus (the highlighted row in one color, and the other rows in another color), but that might be because I can only ever get focus in the table view, so perhaps that context is limited to the table.

I’ve seen a recommendation [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810744/uifocusguide-uitableview-and-uibutton) to associate the focus guide with the button instead of the controller’s view, but that didn’t work. Out of desperation, I also tried associating the focus guide with the tableview, but still no luck.

Here are the pertinent methods. Any light anyone can shed will be appreciated! Thanks!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)

    self.focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true

    self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.infoButton]
}

    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

    guard let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView else { return }

    // When the focus engine focuses on the focus guide, we can programmatically tell it which element should be focused next.
    switch nextFocusedView {
    case self.tableView:
        self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.infoButton]

    case self.infoButton:
        self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.tableView]

    default:
        self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = []
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just gotten this to work. I added another focus guide below the table view, to the left of the button. I sized it to be the width of the tableview and the height of the button. I made its preferredFocusEnvironment the tableView. But that in itself wasn't enough. I then *removed* the didUpdateFocus method, and left and right swiping started working! Here's the resulting code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide1)
    self.focusGuide1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide1.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.infoButton]

    self.view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide2)
    self.focusGuide2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.infoButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.focusGuide2.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.tableView]
}
```